# How to ignore unique violation during insert list of objects which contain set of object

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql-9.1, spring-data-jpa

I use PostgreSQL nad Spring data JPA with Hibernate. I have relation OneToMany with orphanRemoval = false because I very often add many childs to relation.

Parent:

> @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
>       public Set getChildren() {
>           return children;
>       }

Child:

> @ManyToOne
>       @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
>       public Parent getParent() {
>           return parent;
>       }

To persist or merge object I use method

> Iterable< T > save(Iterable< extends T> entities)

form CrudRepository. I save list of parents, where every parent contain set of child. Child table has unique constraint. If constraint violations occurs I want to ignore that and ommit (do not persist) child which cases viloations but I want insert every child which doesn't case constraint violation. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle this dirty by Exceptions.

1. Try to Update the Database, if fine break here.
   Catch the UniqueViolationException and find the JDBCException. Upcast to your qualified Database Exception and find the broken Children.
2. Remove the Children from the Parent.
3. Go to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is to filter the Entitys who will produce unique-violation-exceptions. 
After you filtered that entitys, you can save the good ones.

Exceptions should used as they realy are: Exceptions.

Comment: I agree with you but in this scenerio I have to select all children from database before insert. It results in more operations to do. I specially set orphanRemoval to false to avoid it. I am beginer in ORM and I noticed that if you do not care about number of operations and complexity then ORM is easy to use. But if you want to reduce unnecessary opertions then problems occure.

Comment: "if you do not care about number of operations then xxx is easy to use.", xxx could be any abstraction: jni, ajax, sql, http, queues, newsletters, fishing, fighting, maze-clearing ;)

Comment: This is not a clean way, because somebody may add new entities in another transaction and you may get unique violation exception anyway.

Comment: @mpr You mean unique constraint violation exceptions. Thats why we have the I in ACID. But you are right: deferred constraints and dirty reads can construct such a violation against ACID.

Comment: I did not write anything about dirty reads and deferred constraints. In 'read commited' transaction isolation level approach you described does not work neither.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Postgres-specific answer and not very kosher, but you could employ a similar approach with different DBs:

take the advantage of `on conflict` clause in native Postgres `insert` statement. That way you won't have to handle the unique constraint exceptions at all, the DB will solve the conflicts for you as it encounters them.

1. Prepare a native SQL insert statement e.g.
   `insert into child (id, parent_id, data) values (:id, :parent_id, :data) on conflict do nothing`
2. Use the previously written statement with  `javax.persistence.EntityManager#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String)`

```
EntityManager.createNativeQuery(sql)
                .setParameter("id", it.id)
                .setParameter("parent_id", parentId)
                .setParameter("data", it.data)
                .executeUpdate()
```

1. Repeat for all the children